# Prevent duplicate output in collatz sequence

Tags: python, function, loops

I'm trying to obtain an output of the collatz sequence using python and I more or less got it, but there are duplicates in the output. Can't seem to figure out how to prevent this even after comparing my code with code that doesn't result in the duplicates. Am about 1 month into learning python, so this is my first practice program involving functions. Thanks in advance!

This is my code:

```
def collatz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        result = int(number) // 2
        print(result)
        return result
    elif number % 2 == 1:
        result = 3 * int(number) + 1
        print(result)
        return result

print('Enter a number:')
inputValue = int(input())
while inputValue != 1:
    collatz(inputValue)
    inputValue = collatz(inputValue)
```

And the output is:

```
Enter a number:
5
16
16
8
8
4
4
2
2
1
1
```

I was expecting the output to be this instead:

```
Enter number:
5
16
8
4
2
1
```

Comment: Why are you calling `collatz()` twice per iteration of your `while` loop?  The first time is pointless, since you throw away the return value - but the `print` inside the function still gets executed.

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks a lot, that cleared up my confusion! I called collatz() the first time because I was under the impression that it needs to be stated alone for the function to be called. But I see how it works now while being assigned under inputValue.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.